# dynamic page caching in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching

How to add dynamic caching to time or I should use fragment caching?

I tried to follow [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching-revised) but nothing works.

_feed.html.rb

```
<% cache feed do %>
  <div class="feed">
  <div id="time">
    <%= render 'shared/time' unless @page_caching %>
  </div>
  <p class="pull-right grey"><%= time_ago_in_words(feed.posted_at) %></p>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <p class="grey"><%= image_tag feed.profile_pic, :class => 'pic', :size => '15x15' %> @<%= feed.name %></p>
    </div>
    <p class="content"><%= raw auto_link(feed.content, :username_include_symbol => true, :target => '_blank') %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

_time.html.rb

```
<p class="pull-right grey"><%= time_ago_in_words(feed.posted_at) %></p>
```

index.js.rb

```
$('#feeds').append('<%= j render(@feeds) %>');
<% if @feeds.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@feeds) %>');
<% else %>
$('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>

$('#time').prepend('<%= j render("shared/time") %>');
```

feeds_cotroller.rb

```
  def index
    @page_caching = true
    @feeds = Feed.page(params[:page]).per_page(12)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using helpers that changes over time should not be used inside a cache block.  The best solution to this is to use a js plugin that will insert the time string for you.  google for timeago js plugin and you'll get a bunch of useful results.  The first result there is in http://timeago.yarp.com/.  Using that plugin,  your code should look like the following (i've inserted a script which should insert the time string)

```
<% cache feed do %>
  <div class="feed">
    <div id="time">
      <%= render 'shared/time' unless @page_caching %>
    </div>

    <p class="pull-right grey timeago" title="<%= feed.posted_at %>"></p>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("p.timeago").timeago() })
    </script>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <p class="grey">
        <%= image_tag feed.profile_pic, :class => 'pic', :size => '15x15' %> @<%= feed.name %>
      </p>
    </div>

    <p class="content"><%= raw auto_link(feed.content, :username_include_symbol => true, :target => '_blank') %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is a simple implementation.  You probably want to move the js call to an asset file so you dont have to call it inside the cache.  Anyway, this should give you an idea.